# Change Windows storage size measurement from 1024 to 1000?

Tags: windows-7, storage

Is there a way to change the way Windows calculates storage size/capacity?

I've recently got myself a 2TB drive only to discover Windows reports it as being 1.81TB. I know why, this goes back years of how the industry measures data storage size. As of 1998 it seems that the standard that was decided on by the industry was to go with the base 10 sizing definition, so 1mb = 1000kb.

Linux uses the new industry standard, but it looks like Windows is one of the last big players still using this 1024 definition and I'm essentially looking for a way to change the way this is calculated.

Obviously this is just a personal preference thing, be interesting to hear if this gets on anyone else's nerves or if there are any patches/registry tweaks that can be done to change the way Windows presents it.

Comment: Stop using Windows, there is no way to change this in Windows.

Comment: _"as of 1998..."_ It is a common misconception that HD makers switched to "decimal prefixes" because they wanted to make their devices seem larger, but actually this convention goes back to the original "hard drive", the IBM 350 RAMAC and continuing all the way through the first PC hard drives to today. Hard drives have _always_ been labeled using "decimal prefixes", or more properly, SI prefixes. Binary prefixes make sense for main memory because it is convenient to make it in sizes that are powers of 1024,but hard drives have no such influence.

Comment: It's still has the same amount of space, it's just reported differently.

Comment: Yea, aware it is the same, just different counting method, just wondered if there was any way it could be changed.

Comment: you'll probably have to learn reverse engineering or find someone who can do it, then find all the places in various shell/explorer exes and DLLs and patch those